# How to add the elements with the same ending number in the same array? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I have my code below and I am attempting to create new arrays, in which the numbers in the elements increment by 1 whenever the user adds a book. For instance, when the user already has 1 book added and when he adds another one the array should read as `["bookTitle2,"bookAuthor2", "bookPublisher2", "bookNumOfPages2"]`

```
let bookDetails = ["bookTitle", "bookAuthor", "bookPublisher", "bookNumOfPages"]
var bookDetail = ""
var bookNumber = Int()
var bookNumArray = [Int]()

if bookNumArray.contains(bookNumber) {

print("Book already exists")

} else {

while bookNumber < 2 {

    bookNumber += 1

    bookNumArray.append(bookNumber)

    for detail in bookDetails {

        bookDetail = "\(detail)" + String(bookNumber)

        let newBookArray = [bookDetail]

        print(newBookArray)


    }

}


    }
```

When I run the code above, this shows up instead:

```
["bookTitle1"]
["bookAuthor1"]
["bookPublisher1"]
["bookNumOfPages1"]
["bookTitle2"]
["bookAuthor2"]
["bookPublisher2"]
["bookNumOfPages2"]
```

So I want all the strings that end with 1 in one array and those that end in 2 in another array.

Comment: still unclear ! :(

Comment: did you try Dictionary ?

Comment: The problem is that your entire idea of attaching the number to the name, as in `"bookTitle1"`, is a poor model. Use a dictionary where the name is the key and the value is the count (a histogram).

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm never good at asking questions lol. So basically, I want to print out ["bookTitle1", "bookAuthor1", "bookPublisher1", "bookNumOfPages1"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
for detail in bookDetails {

    bookDetail = "\(detail)" + String(bookNumber)

    let newBookArray = [bookDetail]

    print(newBookArray)
}
```

For every iteration you are creating a new array with the current detail e.g bookTitle into an array of your string var `bookDetail` declared outside of this loop's scope.

Also note that `newBookArray` is a local variable, so it will be destroyed when it gets out of the loop. You would need an array of `bookDetail` to store the `newBookArray`.

```
let bookDetails = ["bookTitle", "bookAuthor", "bookPublisher", "bookNumOfPages"]
var bookDetailArray : [Array<String>] = [] //Your array to store all the bookDetails
var bookDetail : [String] = [] //Your array to store a bookDetail
var bookNumber = Int()
var bookNumArray = [Int]()
```

Then you can do:

```
bookDetail.removeAll() //Clear all objects before appending new one

for detail in bookDetails {

    bookDetail.append("\(detail) + String(bookNumber)")
}

bookDetailArray.append(bookDetail)
```

Just a suggestion: As other people said, a dictionary or a class for the bookDetail properties would be a better model in your case. Read up on Object-oriented programming if you ever plan to use a class.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look up on those topics but you helped me solve my problem on my level so I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @acoustickat no problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do a dictionary or create a class bookDetails with properties like bookTitle, bookAuthor, etc. And then I would create an array of the instances of this class.

If you want to do it your way, Why not create a two-way array, something like:

```
var arrayFinal = [[""]]
var bookNumber = 0

// Whenever the action is triggered

bookNumber += 1

var bookDetails = ["bookTitle", "bookAuthor", "bookPublisher", "bookNumOfPages"]

for detail in bookDetails 
{
    detail = "\(detail) +\(bookNumber)"
}

arrayFinal.add(bookDetails)
```

Or something like that...

Comment: Thanks! I will try dictionary :)

Comment: @acoustickat better to create a struct with the properties you need